# Yii form ajax request CSRF token error

Tags: php, ajax, yii, csrf

I trying to get list of districts depends on country, but when I changed country I got error:

> **The CSRF token could not be verified.**

Code:

```
<?php
echo $form->dropDownList(
        $generalInfoForm,
        'country',
        CHtml::listData(Countries::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'name')), 'code', 'name'),
        array(
            'prompt' => '(Select country)',
            'ajax' => array(
                'type'=>'POST',
                'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('//user/auth/loadcities'),
                'update'=>'#city_name',
                'data'=> array(
                    'YII_CSRF_TOKEN' => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken,
                    'country_id'=>'js:this.value'
                ),
            )
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'form_input_password bx-def-font',
            'id' => 'general_info_country',
            'placeholder' => Yii::t('UserModule.views_auth_login', 'password')
        )
);
?>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: POST parameters:YII_CSRF_TOKEN:662a601590169ed9fcd8542167c0f8d066d0e72c,
country_id:AGO

Comment: Are you sure `Yii::app()->request->csrfToken` is correct? It would seem to me that you'd need to get a new token, not reuse the one of the current request.

Comment: @Halcyon you mean I must create new token for each ajax request? I just debug url '//user/auth/loadcities'  and there exactly the same token .

Comment: I think you're using the _synchronizer token pattern_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Synchronizer_token_pattern I'm not familiar enough with Yii to tell how to use their csrf functions. I think you don't need to specify the token yourself. Set `enableCsrfValidation` and Yii will take care of it for you.

Comment: enableCsrfValidation is  set to true. I looked for answer in web and everything looks good in my code, but did not work for me.... And i'm new in Yii too

Comment: Use this worked for me  on ajax post                                                                              $csrfTokenName = Yii::app()->request->csrfTokenName;
$csrfToken = Yii::app()->request->csrfToken;

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing 'YII_CSRF_TOKEN' to 'CSRF_TOKEN'